# I18n month translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm trying to translate a month with I18n and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for "2015-05-18":String
```

Code:

```
# controller
@previous_month = I18n.l(Date.today - (1%12).months)

# view
@previous_month.strftime('%B')
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller:

```
@previous_month = Date.today - (1%12).months
```

view:

```
I18n.l @previous_month, :format => "%B"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it that with a string but yes with date

`@previous_month = Date.today - (1%12).months`

`@previous_month.strftime('%B')`